# Why does clicking a link rendered by WP PHP with target="_blank" open in new tab and current tab?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, hyperlink

So I know this kind of question has been asked in here, but mine appears to be different from others.

The code below shows that if there is a URL populate it and open it in a new tab, however, for some strange reason the link opens in a new tab (YAY!!) AND opens in the current tab (BOO!!). Why is it opening in both the new tab and the current tab?

I just checked in an incognito window and it happens there also so it doesn't appear to be a cookie issue either.

```
<div class="box span4">
    <?php if( $url1 != '' && $img1 != '' ): ?>
        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $url1 ); ?>" target="_blank" class="box-link">
            <center><img class="box-image" src="<?php echo esc_url( $img1 ); ?>"/></center>
        </a>
    <?php else: ?>
        <?php if( $img1 != '' ): ?>
            <a class="box-no-url">
                <center><img class="box-image" src="<?php echo esc_url( $img1 ); ?>"/></center>
            </a>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <p><?php echo wp_kses( $text1, array( 'br' => array(), 'em' => array(), 'strong' => array() ) ); ?></p>
</div>
```

To see this code in action please visit http://www.tayloredhomeinspection.com/ and scroll down to the image with the InterNACHI seal in the middle gray box and click on it (or the text below it).

Comment: what is the output of `esc_url( $url1 )`? could there be some Javascript that listens for clicks on anchor tags that would cause this behavior?

Comment: Hey Sam, the output of esc_url( $url1 ); ? is a URL entered in the Box Lite area of this Word Press theme - so it could be considered a variable or http://www.example.com

Answer (score 5):

#### The cause

There is a script tag in the header section of the HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.tayloredhomeinspection.com/wp-content/themes/parallax1/elements/lib/js/elements.min.js?ver=4.7.5"></script>
```

Inside [that file](http://www.tayloredhomeinspection.com/wp-content/themes/parallax1/elements/lib/js/elements.min.js?ver=4.7.5) is the following block (un-minified, thanks to [jsbeautifier.org](http://jsbeautifier.org/)):

```
jQuery(".boxes .box").each(function() {
    var e = jQuery(this).children(".box-link").attr("href");
    jQuery(this).hover(function() {
        if (e && e != "") jQuery(this).css("cursor", "pointer")
    }, function() {
        jQuery(this).css("cursor", "default")
    });
    jQuery(this).click(function() {
        if (e && e != "") window.location = e
    })
});
```

That code is looking for elements (child elements of elements with class *boxes* and *box*, respectively) with class *box-link* and when any of those elements is clicked on, it changes the location of the current tab (by assigning a value to [window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location)) to the value at the *href* attribute of the element (with class *box-link*).

That link (that contains the InterNACHI seal) has class *box-link* and matches those CSS selectors:

```
<div class="boxes">
        <!-- removed first box -->

        <div class="box span4" style="cursor: default; height: 460px;">
            <a href="http://www.nachi.org/" target="_blank" class="box-link">
                <center><img class="box-image" src="./Taylored Home Inspection 719.602.6287_files/internachi_red_gold.png"></center>
            </a>
```

It appears that this allows the user to click anywhere in the parent container (with `class="box"`), for instance - on the paragraph below the link, and still have the effect of clicking on the link. See the differences between the link and paragraph illustrated in the screenshot below:

[image]

#### Prevention

One quick solution would be to remove that class name (i.e. *box-link*) from that element. However that remove desired styling...  Beyond that, one might need to modify the (wordpress) JavaScript to stop changing the location if the anchor tag has a target and it was the target of the event.

#### Update:

If no help is found from the CyberChimp Parallax Word Press theme documentation and/or support, an alteration script could be run after the page has loaded. The code below could be added to any javascript file run after the other javascript files (including *elements.min.js*)), or inline in a script tag (i.e. `<script type="text/javascript">jQuery(".boxes .box" ...</script>`).

One could argue though that this is just a hack to cover up functionality and might suffer if the implementation in the theme code changes.

```
jQuery(".boxes .box").each(function() {
    var e = jQuery(this).children(".box-link").attr("href");
    var target = jQuery(this).children(".box-link").attr('target');
    if (target == '_blank') {
      jQuery(this).off('click');
    }
    jQuery(this).click(function(event) {
      if (e && e != "") {
          if (target == '_blank') {
              window.open( e, '_blank');
          }
          else { 
              window.location = e;
          }
      }
    });
  });
```

See a demonstration in [this jsbin example](http://jsbin.com/vacumo/2/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Hi Sam, This is a great and detailed explanation of what is going on - and I agree with it. I've tried removing the class box-link and it does hose the styling. I've gone into the JS and modified window.location=e to window.open=e and window.open=e, '_blank' and of course I put the target="_blank" in the php to add it to the html. I get a new tab that goes to www.nachi.org, but the current tab still, also, goes to www.nachi.org. I do appreciate you digging into this though!!! Thanks!

Comment: Is there a specific plug-in or part of the theme that you are using that instructed you to add those classes (e.g. _box_, _box-link_)? If so, perhaps the documentation might mention ways to work around the link issues, or if it is a github repo we could submit a pull request...

Comment: No, it's part of the CyberChimp Parallax Word Press theme. I'll dig into the documentation to see if there is anything in there, I've also posted this issue on the CyberChimps support forum to see if they can help.

Comment: You may also want to look into changing out that center tag :P

Comment: @DavidTaylor see my updated answer for a possible approach you could take to remedy the situation

Comment: @SamOnela - Thank you. That worked after I weaved it into the elements.min.js file.

Comment: Great - if you believe this is the best solution, please [accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). For more information, see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Also, if you believe it is useful, consider giving it an [upvote](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) (you will need 15+ reputation first).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the weave job I did that seems to have it working.

```
jQuery(window).load(function(e) {
 if (jQuery(window).width() > 767) {
  setTimeout(function() {
   jQuery("#widget_boxes_container .box").css("height", 
jQuery("#widget_boxes_container").height() - 20)
  }, 500)
 }
 jQuery(".boxes .box").each(function() {
  var e = jQuery(this).children(".box-link").attr("href");
  var target = jQuery(this).children(".box-link").attr("target");
  if (target == "_blank") {
      jQuery(this).off("click");
  }
  jQuery(this).hover(function() {
   if (e && e != "") jQuery(this).css("cursor", "pointer")
  }, function() {
   jQuery(this).css("cursor", "default")
  });
  jQuery(this).click(function(event) {
      if (e && e != "") {
          if (target == "_blank") {
              window.open( e, "_blank");
          }
          else { 
              window.location = e;
          }
      }
    });
 jQuery(".carousel").carousel("cycle")
})
```

It looks like I have to keep the `target="_blank"` in the .php file and this should work for any changes I make in the theme and I have the file saved in case of theme updates.

Comment: While this summarizes your solution, it doesn't really answer the question of why the tab was being opened and the location changed. A more appropriate action would be to reply in a comment to my answer, with a link to another site like [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/) where you could share your code. If you want feedback on the code, perhaps you should post it on http://codereview.stackexchange.com.